# Mysql - order by custom?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query that is returning the following data:

```
select Desc,Value from table;

Desc        Value
 a           4
 r           3
 e           4
 j           7
 w           6
 p           6
```

I want to order by Descr but in a specific order (This specific is required for json)

```
Desc        Value
 r           3  
 a           4
 e           4
 j           7
 p           6
 w           6
```

Is this possible?

Comment: If the order you want is arbitrary (as far as SQL is concerned), I would say it's going to be too complicated and you should attempt to order it in a serverside implementation language (e.g. PHP) instead where custom ordering functions are much more native/common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ORDER BY FIELD(`desc`, 'r', 'a', 'e', 'j', 'p', 'w')
```

Note: if `desc` value doesn't match the given values, it will come first, as `FIELD()` would return `0`

Comment: Awesome! That was easy. Thanks

Comment: Nice trick! Just learnt something new - today was a good day.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but you can order by `(condition) DESC`. `DESC` because if the condition is true it's *more* than if the condition is false:

```
SELECT
    Desc,
    Value
FROM
    Foo
ORDER BY
    (Desc = 'r') DESC,
    (Desc = 'a') DESC,
    (Desc = 'e') DESC,
    (Desc = 'j') DESC,
    (Desc = 'p') DESC,
    (Desc = 'w') DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You could order by a `case` expression that specifies the ordering you want:

```
SELECT   `desc`, `value`
FROM     my_table
ORDER BY CASE `desc` WHEN 'r' THEN 1 
                     WHEN 'a' THEN 2
                     WHEN 'e' THEN 3
                     WHEN 'j' THEN 4
                     WHEN 'p' THEN 5
                     WHEN 'w' THEN 6
                     ELSE 999 --for completeness sake
          END CASE ASC
```