# Solr sorting by result

Tags: php, apache, solr

I have indexed a table which is giving me result like following

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
H
H
A
B
```

I want to sort result in such a manner that I get H first everytime and then rest should be sort by asc like

```
H
H
A
A
B
B
C
D
so on...
```

I am not finding a way for this. Please help.

Comment: suppose it as result of any column i.e Alphabets

Comment: `sort by desc` means `Z` is First or `A` is first ? In your example `A` is First.

Comment: yes you are right, let suppose its asc. Main concern is i would like to sort in such a manner that i can put particular text first then sort others.

Comment: column value getting from database as `array` or `string` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22698344/mysql-order-by-custom

Comment: I am getting it as array, but i dont want to sort array I would like to get result based on Solr sorting.

Comment: Please help. If somebody have some idea about how to  achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the search query you are using in order to get the results. You could modify your query parameter so that it matches the exact result you want to be on the top, and pass the original query in q.alt parameter, and then apply the sorting you wish to use.

Note that in order to use q.alt, you need to use dismax or edismax query parser.

Comment: Thanks. Can you let me know how this will work Do I need to pass q.alt=H after setting dismax and edismax to true? I checked it like this and doestn't get desired result.

Comment: q.alt=[Your Query parameter]:H&defType=edismax

Answer (score 1):

```
$alpha = array("A","B","C","D","E","F","H","H","A","B");

$first = array("H");
$alpha =array_diff($alpha, $first);
asort($alpha);
$alpha= $first + $alpha;
```

**[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/a3P7Dv)**

Comment: Thanks for this. But I would like to do this sorting via solr